# WPF AvalonDock add Documents

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, avalondock

I have a Window with AvalonDock. On startup there is one Document opened which is filled with LocControllers usercontrols (LocControllersViewModel).

Now I want to have that when there is doubleclicked on a LocController that the LocController usercontrol opens in a new Document. So the first document is always the overview, filled with LocController usercontrols, and the other Documents are added after a double click.

I've looked at the AvalonDock and MVVM sample, but I can't figure out how to get the behavior that I want.

What I've found out so far is that I have to use the DocumentsSource property to bind the documents. So I guess I need to create a collection of DocumentViewModels to bind to the DocumentsSource property. That DocumentViewModel I need to fill with usercontrols. For the first Document is will be a list of LocController usercontrols, for the other Documents it can be other usercontrols.

Can anyone provide me with a small code example? i don't think it is that hard, but I just can't find it :(

EDIT: Here's my current DockingManager XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="AvalonDockMvvmTest.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
                xmlns:AvalonDockMvvmTest="clr-namespace:AvalonDockMvvmTest"
                Title="MainWindow"
                Height="350"
                Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="NewDetail"
                                    Command="{Binding NewCommand}" />
                <MenuItem Header="OpenSelectDetail"
                                    Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager"
                                                 Margin="3 0 3 0"
                                                 DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

            <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
                <AvalonDockMvvmTest:PanesTemplateSelector>
                    <AvalonDockMvvmTest:PanesTemplateSelector.OverViewTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type AvalonDockMvvmTest:OverviewViewModel}"> <!-- Overview user control -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </AvalonDockMvvmTest:PanesTemplateSelector.OverViewTemplate>

                    <AvalonDockMvvmTest:PanesTemplateSelector.DetailTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type AvalonDockMvvmTest:DetailViewModel}"> <!-- Detail user control -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </AvalonDockMvvmTest:PanesTemplateSelector.DetailTemplate>

                </AvalonDockMvvmTest:PanesTemplateSelector>
            </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
        </xcad:DockingManager>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So how do I load the different controls (overview and detail) to the document pane?

Comment: I'll try to simplefy my question. I have several different usercontrols, like an overviewControl, detailControl, etc. Now I want to load the overviewControl at start up in the first DocumentTab. If in the overviewControl is doubleclicked on an item, it needs to open the detailControl on a new DocumentTab. How can I accomplish this? It can't be that hard I would think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it took me some time, but I finally got it working the way I want.
Picking code from the AvalonDock MMVM sample and the CodeProject 'AvalonDock [2.0] Tutorial'

The result: when the application starts the overview is loaded in the first document tab.
When you click the newdetail menuitem, a new document tab is added, after the overview tab.
The overview tab is set to be unable to close.

There are some more things to do, like adding a side - and bottom panel. So I'm not done yet, but I think if I got so far the other panels can be done too.

Screenshot:

[image: AvalonDock MVVM]

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AvalonDockMvvmTest.View.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
                xmlns:Pane="clr-namespace:AvalonDockMvvmTest.View.Pane"
                xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:AvalonDockMvvmTest.ViewModel"
                Title="MainWindow"
                Height="350"
                Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Region Menu-->
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="NewDetail"
                                    Command="{Binding NewCommand}" />
                <MenuItem Header="OpenSelectDetail"
                                    Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <!-- EndRegion Menu-->

        <!-- Region DockingManager -->
        <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager"
                                                 Margin="3 0 3 0"
                                                 DocumentsSource="{Binding Files}"
                                                 Grid.Row="1">

            <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
                <Pane:PanesTemplateSelector>
                    <!-- Overview (startpage)-->
                    <Pane:PanesTemplateSelector.OverViewTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:OverviewViewModel}">
                            <!-- Add UserControl here-->
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentText}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Pane:PanesTemplateSelector.OverViewTemplate>

                    <!--Detail controls-->
                    <Pane:PanesTemplateSelector.DetailTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:DetailViewModel}">
                            <!-- Add UserControl here-->
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentText}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Pane:PanesTemplateSelector.DetailTemplate>
                </Pane:PanesTemplateSelector>
            </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>

            <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
                <Pane:PanesStyleSelector>
                    <!-- Overview (startpage) style -->
                    <Pane:PanesStyleSelector.OverviewStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Title"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                            <Setter Property="CloseCommand"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
                            <Setter Property="ContentId"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Pane:PanesStyleSelector.OverviewStyle>
                    <!-- Detail style -->
                    <Pane:PanesStyleSelector.DetailStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Title"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                            <Setter Property="ContentId"
                                            Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Pane:PanesStyleSelector.DetailStyle>
                </Pane:PanesStyleSelector>
            </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
        </xcad:DockingManager>
        <!-- EndRegion DockingManager -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```